# Button moves to the right on hover

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am using the WordPress File Upload Plugin and is working fine, but on hover the button to select a file to upload, the button moves to the right.
I think the following CSS is the important part.

```
input[type="button"].file_input_button{
    width:100px;
    height:27px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#EEE;
    color:#555;
    background-image:url(white-grad-active.png);
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#BBB;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -khtml-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px
}
input[type="button"].file_input_button_hover{
    width:100px;
    height:27px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#EEE;
    color:#111;
    background-image:url(white-grad-active.png);
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#333;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -khtml-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px
}
input[type="button"].file_input_button:disabled,input[type="button"].file_input_button_hover:disabled{
    width:100px;
    height:27px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#EEE;
    color:silver;
    background-image:url(white-grad-active.png);
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#BBB;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -khtml-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px
}
```

What is the CSS code that is causing this?
How can I remove this behavior?
Can I disable the .file_input_button_hover CSS?

This CSS it came with the plugin and I can't get rid from it.

UPDATE:

Playing with Chrome's Developer Tools I saw that on hover the class of the button changed from file_input_button to file_input_button_hover and position changed from nothing to "position: absolute;"

I don't know why but adding the following to the custom CSS solved the issue:

```
input[type="button"].file_input_button_hover{
position: relative !important;
}

input[type="button"].file_input_button_hover{
position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: Only having this isn't enough for us to figure out what is wrong. This should work fine, but perhaps you have some other css that is interfering. Is that all the css that is applied to that button?

Comment: you can try this line in your custom css. input[type="button"], input[type="button"]:hover{float:left !important;}

Comment: I can't find anything in what you've posted that would cause the shift. As was already mentioned, the various CSS states are identical. https://jsfiddle.net/uyz1s47t/

Comment: Apparently those bits of CSS are not the problem. There must be something else in your CSS that's causing the shift. You can check which rules are being applied with your Chrome developer tools, just inspect the element and apply the filters with the :hov button to compare both states and check where the conflicting rule is coming from

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is with the `file_input_button_hover` class, set the `left` value to `0`